# Access bpy.data in Blender addon

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I was getting the error

> AttributeError: '_RestrictContext' object has no attribute...

with my addon (in Blender 2.72), then I found that access to bpy.context and bpy.data is restricted in addon code, as explained here

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/API_Changes#Restricted_Context

Instead of using bpy.context, I can use the context parameter of execute() and invoke(). But what can I use instead of bpy.data?

Comment: I have solved this by moving the  data access outside the `register()` function

Comment: I have no access to bpy.data in register(), only in functions called by invoke() and execute(). I get the error when using the operator defined by the addon.

Comment: the restriction is in un/register() only,  can you put a link to your code

Comment: My mistake, I actually had an access to bpy.data before register(), in "from bpy import data as D" at the beginning of my code. I removed that and now it works. Thank you!